# Is there a way in C++ to restrict a function of a given class to another class only(without using inheritance, friend)?

Tags: c++, oop, api-design, class-design, access-modifiers

I want to design a class having a function which should be restricted to be called from another class only. Specifically, in the given code

```
class Club
{
    int id;
    string name;
    vector<string> members;
    int generateId() 
    { 
        static int i=1;
        return i++;
    }
public:
    Club(string name) { this->name = name; this->id = generateId(); }  
    void registerMember(string memberName) { members.push_back(memberName); }
    int getId() { return id; }
};

class Application
{
    vector<Club> clubs;
public:
    void registerClub(Club &club) { clubs.push_back(club); }
    void addMemberToClub(int clubId, string memberName)
    {
        for(Club club: clubs)
        {
            if(clubId == club.getId())
                club.registerMember(memberName);
        }
    }
};
```

An user(public user) can create an object of the class `Club` and register using the function `registerMember()` since it's public. I want the user to register via an object of the class `Application`, using the `addMemberToClub()` function only. If the user goes by the former way mentioned, I can't keep track of the user. Is there a way to enforce the latter?

1. I don't want to use the access modifier `protected` since inheritance has no meaning here.
2. I don't want to use the `friend` keyword, since it's considered bad practice.

Comment: `friend` seems appropriate here. What's the issue with that? I'm not aware of a guideline that says never use `friend`.

Comment: @cigien Trying to keep this language independent.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Your title says "in C++" so it's not language agnostic

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You would eventually have to implement it in *some* language, and different languages have different mechanisms to achieve similar effects. And what @BenVoigt said :)

Comment: That's okay .. using a friend accomplishes the task. Is there any other way by which this can be achieved?

Comment: An alternative to `friend` is to add a dummy argument of a data type which only the intended caller knows how to construct.  This can be used to enable access to only a single member function, rather than giving access to all private members at once as `friend` does.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Voigt. Can you kindly provide an example for this?

Comment: @BenVoigt Seems like this would allow anyone who reads the source code to call the function, without modifying `Club`.

Comment: Please correct me here ... even if one doesn't read the source code, using intellisense, one can figure out the type of the third argument, and construct it or send NULL in it's place.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: NULL is a pointer, it can't be converted to an arbitrary object.  This is not Java.  C++ access controls apply to constructors and destructors also.

Comment: @cigien: example posted, please show your attack (to be fair, I did switch from a dummy argument to a dummy return type, and restricted the destructor rather than the constructor)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "lock-and-key" way to permit another class (and only that class) or even a single function in another class to access just one member function, unlike `friend` which exposes all private members at the same time:

```
#include <iostream>

class Key;

class Locked
{
    static const char* const Greeting;
public:
    static Key secretive();
    static void attacker();
};

struct Admin
{
    void doit();
};

class Key
{
    ~Key() = default;
    //friend class Admin;
    friend void Admin::doit();
    friend Key Locked::secretive();
};

void Admin::doit()
{
    Locked::secretive();
    std::cout << Locked::Greeting; // compile error
}

constexpr const char* Locked::Greeting = "Hello!\n";

Key Locked::secretive()
{
    std::cout << Greeting;
    return Key();
}

void Locked::attacker()
{
    std::cout << Locked::Greeting; // ok, it's just private
    Locked::secretive(); // compile error, it's locked down tight
}

int main()
{
    Admin a;
    a.doit();
    std::cout << Locked::Greeting; // compile error
    Locked::secretive(); // compile error
}
```

It also works around the "which class is declared first?" problem that prevents two classes from mutually friending individual member functions of each other, because the restricted operation needs to follow only a forward declaration of the key type; the full definition of the other type can (and in this example does) appear above the key definition, allowing individual members to be named in the key type's friend directive.

Note that in this solution the ["obvious" fact that other members of the same class can access the locked function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781163/is-there-a-way-in-c-to-restrict-a-function-of-a-given-class-to-another-class-o/61785164#comment109284971_61781299) is NOT true.  The compiler prevents `Locked::attacker()` from calling `Locked::secretive()`.

Note also that I've used `static` in this example to minimize the number of objects I had to create, but the approach works just fine for non-static member functions too.

---

A potentially MUCH easier way to restrict what part of the program can call your protected function is with a simple flag:

```
class Application
{
    static bool addingMember = 0;
public:
    static bool isRegistrationOk() { return addingMember; }
    void registerClub(Club &club) { clubs.push_back(club); }
    void addMemberToClub(int clubId, string memberName)
    {
        addingMember = true;
        for(Club club: clubs)
        {
            if(clubId == club.getId())
                club.registerMember(memberName);
        }
        addingMember = false;
    }
};

void Club::registerMember(string memberName)
{
    assert(Application::isRegistrationOk());
    members.push_back(memberName);
}
```

Much easier to grok, but it's a runtime check not compile-time, and requires additional work to be made thread-safe.  But it accomplishes the goal with no usage of `friend` or inheritance.

Comment: It took me whole 5 minutes of staring at the code (I was too lazy to run it and check what compiler says:) ) to work out WHY does that work this way, and I see it now: the Key has a private destructor, and it 'friends' a specific target function `secretive`, and that latter function returns the discardable unused `Key` object. It's discardable and unused, but formally still needs to be destroyed even if it's going to be optimized out, and now the `attacker` cannot do that, as the ~dtor is not accessible at this scope. OTOH, `doit` can, as it is friended as well. Nice one! Good trick!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Your analysis is exactly correct.  `Admin::doit()` (as well as recursive calls from `secretive()` itself) is the only function that can call `Locked::secretive()`.  Originally I didn't even friend `secretive()` but although the compiler didn't complain, falling off the end of a non-void-returning function is undefined behavior, so I had to add the return statement and then that needed access to the destructor as well.

Answer (score 1):

`friend` is an appropriate mechanism to use in this case. Make `registerMember` private in `Club`, and `Club` can grant friendship to `Application`:

```
class Club
{
    // ...
    void registerMember(string memberName) { members.push_back(memberName); }
public:
    // ...
    friend class Application;
};
```

Now only `Application` can call `registerMember`, and `Club` as well, of course.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fMecsw).

Comment: "*Now only `Application` can call `registerMember`*" - and `Club` can call it too, of course.

Comment: Haha, true. Seemed so obvious that I didn't even think to write it down. Thanks :)